# How to create a border for scrollable text using unordered lists

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

At the moment my application uses `Socket.IO` and `node.js` as the server. Every time someone sends a message, it appends itself onto an unordered list which then correctly shows itself on the page. The problem is that the area where the user enters their message is at the bottom, and when many messages are posted eventually the latest `<li>` tags start to show under the text box where users enter messages. A few messages later a scroll bar will appear which will let you read the messages you were not previously allowed to read, but then the latest messages again show beneath the text box. My temporary (Really bad) solution is to check the length of the message list and delete the last message in the list once it hits a certain number.

Comment: Could you show use the HTML? It sounds like you need to add things inside `<div>` tags: main post, replies, textbox to answer... should be separate divisions.

Comment: I already have the text input box and the UL in separate divs